# Are there any alternatives to testing the code changes locally by doing the Maven Build?

Tags: maven, build

If I want to test my changes, I do it in the local setup by making changes in the .war files of the project. This is a time consuming process. Is there any alternative to this testing step ? Any software or tool which helps me test my changes without building again ?

Comment: Using an IDE like Eclipse for this?

Comment: You'd need to provide more details on your technologies. EJB ? Spring ? Spring-Boot ? Which container you deployed to ?

Comment: very broad question too... Depending on the changes, the answer could just be: **JUnit**.

Comment: I work as a front end developer. I code in Eclipse. If I have to test my changes, I need to make changes in the .war files which I get after performing the maven build. So, I just wanted to know if their is any alternative to this complete step?  While doing some research, I came across a software named as 'Fiddler'. I am not sure how it works though. But, I read that what ever changes we make in Eclipse is directly reflected in the browser.